# TextField.clear() & .sendKeys(Keys.chord()) not working on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

i have an issue on iOS - textField.clear does not work(it seems due to iOS + Xcode new versions)
i tried to use the "keyboard" like this

```
.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.BACK_SPACE));
```

but it does not work and i also tried this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
action.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
```

It seems that i cant uses the "keyboard" either

any ideas?
i just want to delete the text in a textfield and enter a new text (on iOS)

Comment: I'm thinking you might be missing some additional question tags here. Perhaps Xamarin?

Comment: If you have the `UITextField` instance, why not replace the contents via the `Text` property